# Overwrite $(document).ajaxStart()

Tags: jquery

I did general pre-loader for my jQuery AJAX calls.
I did used:

```
 $(document).ajaxStart(function(e) {
    objMain.ajaxPreloader.showFn();
 });
```

The problem is that I need to overwrite it in one place for one single call, to not show pre-loader but I don't know how. I did try to console.log `event` to identify the trigger but I cannot find anything which I can use. Is any option to overwrite this config?

Comment: But sometimes this function can be parallel with other calls

Comment: did you also try to `console.log(e)`? :) usually there is a path or url defined which you can test against

Comment: You can disable global events for specific ajax calls with `global: false`. You could use `beforeSend` and `complete` local events to do something different for that one call if you wanted. Have a look at this link for more information. http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

Comment: @Jamie Dunstan This is solution, it's should be the answer.

Comment: @Wado - I have added it as an answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable global events for specific ajax calls with `global: false`.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  global: false,
  // ...
});
```

You could also use `beforeSend` and `complete` local events to do something different for that one call if you wanted. See the example below:

```
$.ajax({
  beforeSend: function(){
      // Handle the beforeSend event
  },
  complete: function(){
     // Handle the complete event
  }
  // ......
});
```

Have a look at [this link](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/) for more information.